# Edit shared preferences from DDMS

Tags: android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences, ddms

I want to edit shared preferences values from DDMS, if I double click the file it doen't saves the changes.
Do I do something wrong or there is special plugin for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should probably make sure your app isn't running before doing this.

You have to use the File Explorer option. Navigate to

> data -> com.yourpackage -> shared_pref

Click the xml and at the top right click `pull`.

Edit the xml on your computer.

Once you're done, click `push` (also top right).

[image]

If you pushed the same file to the same device to the same directory, the next time you launch the app, you should see your updated values.

Comment: @NickF I'm pretty sure that this is the only way. If you don't like the GUI, you can also use `adb pull/push` along with the file path.

Comment: @NickF also worth noting that DDMS' file explorer will definitely work for emulators, but if you're on a phone, your mileage may vary. From what I can recall, to get the files to show in DDMS, you need to do some permissions changes, which requires root.

Comment: What is file explorer? Can I do this using Ecplipse?

Comment: @Buksy This is all done using Eclipse. Open the `DDMS` perspective and there should be a tab called `File Explorer`.

Answer (score 7):

Just follow the steps, it is easy.

Step 1:[image]

Step 2: Open data/data/you package name/shared_prefs -> select your shared pref -> right click and give Save As.

[image]

Step 3: Save in your desired folder. I am saving in desktop folder. Dont change the name
[image]

Step 4: Now edit the needed values in the saved file.

Step 5: Upload the edited file to shared_pref directory
[image]

Finally close and open the app to make it work.
That's all.