# Android - SharedPreference error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Problem: Activity B ALWAYS return false, however, if I check the same KEY inside activity A, the result is true. Why is this? I have checked the KEY, it is exactly the same in both activities.

**Edit:** Thank you all for your help, however after implementing your suggestions, I still have had no luck. Here is what I have now:

`ActivityA, extends Activity Implements OnGesturePerformedListener`

```
//How methods are called...
read(getApplicationContext(),"fav", posName);
write(getApplicationContext(), "fav", posName, false);
...

public Boolean read(Context context, String name, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sP = context.getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean b = sP.getBoolean(key, false);
    return b;
}

public void write(Context context, String name, String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sP = context.getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sP.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

`ActivityB, extends FragmentActivity`, sub class:

`public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment`

Inside `onActivityCreated()`

```
SharedPreferences sP = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("fav", MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean b = sP.getBoolean(posName, false);
```

Results = `b` always equals `false`

Any Ideas?

Comment: What value does the variable `posName` set? Will it always have the same value? You can use the DDMS view to inspect the value of your shared preferences, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913026/edit-shared-preferences-from-ddms

Comment: Can you provide some more contextual code within the actual program? The code we see here seems okay, but it's hard to tell without seeing it in use.

Comment: Hi guys, I have fixed it. The error was a key mismatch. Sorry forgot to update this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getSharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)`:

```
public void write(Context context, String key, boolean value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            NAME_SHAREDPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public Boolean read(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            NAME_SHAREDPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean b = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Android docs:

> Activity persistent state is managed with the method getPreferences(int), allowing you to retrieve and modify a set of name/value pairs associated with the activity. **To use preferences that are shared across multiple application components (activities, receivers, services, providers), you can use the underlying Context.getSharedPreferences() method** to retrieve a preferences object stored under a specific name. 
>   (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

So basically you need to use [Context.getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to share preferences across multiple activities.

Comment: you can get the current context by using this method, getApplicationContext();
So, for accessing shared preferences in other activities just use getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences();

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt the following approach to get same sharedPreference everywhere:

```
SharedPreference mPrefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
 SharedPreference.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
```

I hope it was useful.