# Edit Shared Preferences entry present in running app

Tags: android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences, adb

I want to edit an entry of a sharedPreference file that is in my emulator: /data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/file_name.xml and make this change be applicable to the running app, not recompile it again:

```
<map>
    <string name="orderKey">79160317</string>
    <string name="userId">3103842</string>
    <string name="userToken">eyJhbGciOiJIUeTR1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXJJZCI6IjMxMDM5NDIifSwiaWF0IjoxNTQ0MDE0MzU5qwJleHAiOjE1NDQ4NzgzN7l9.gmqUlMzAUv2rCsGoYBZDTZ3aoYdYnDssdregrEJ&</string>

</map>
```

I have already tried this: [Edit shared preferences from DDMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913026/edit-shared-preferences-from-ddms), but it requires me to run the app again, i.e. that's not dynamic.

Comment: Your question isn't making sense.  If you're asking how to edit a shred preference programmatically, there's dozens of answers on that.  If you're asking how to write a preferences screen, there's lots of answers/tutorials for that as well.  If you're asking something else, please be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You need a debug library like [Pandora](https://github.com/whataa/pandora), [Android-Debug-Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) or [Hyperion-Android](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/Hyperion-Android)