# How can I edit the shared preferences file using Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

During development, I want to manually change some values of the shared preferences file using Android Studio. Android Studio allows opening the XML-file with the Device File Manager. It, however, does not save changes to the file on the device file system.

**Question:** How can I modify values of the shared preferences file on a development device using Android Studio?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14913624/7948109)?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, closing the app does not make a difference.